# Multiple trait entities in wit.ai

Tags: wit.ai

I have created two entities in Wit. One is "sentiment" and one is "category". I've fed them both with labeled data through the HTTP API. Sentiment analysis was working great up until I have added the "category" entity. Now Wit only recognizes categories, it does not look for sentiments. Is it possible to extract two trait entities from a message?